# Observers in Rshiny - Save Button Dependent on Value from SelectizeInput

Tags: shiny, reactive, selectinput, action-button

In my app there are multiple data frames, each corresponding to only one value in a selectizeinput. When the selectizeinput value matches the table's name, the correct data frame is linked to an rhandsontable. There is only one rhandsontable, which is shared by all of the underlying data frames but never at the same time. Users make edits to the selected data frame via the rhandsontable. These edits are saved when a button is clicked. In the example below I have an observeEvent that triggers a save to one of the data frames. This is an issue because if another data frame is selected and edited, the save button will save the values to the other table, not the currently selected one. I know that if else statements, like what I have for swapping in and out the dataframes, within the observeEvent will throw up an argument of zero length. I knew ahead of time that the current observeEvent approach would cause the issue of saving to the wrong table but I wanted to get a partially functional example to begin working with.

Working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)
library(RPostgres)
library(bslib)
library(data.table)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shinyauthr)
library(sodium)
library(rsconnect)

#set up fake usernames and passwords for this working example

user_base <- tibble::tibble(
  user = c("test"),
  password = sapply(c("test"),
                    sodium::password_store),
  permissions = c("test"),
  name = c("test")
)


#USER INTERFACE
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  #boostrap theme and header logo/title
  theme = bs_theme(version = 5, bootswatch = "lumen"),
  
  
  #log out button
  br(),
  div(class = "float-right", shinyauthr::logoutUI(id = "logout")),
  br(),
  br(),
  
  #login section 
  shinyauthr::loginUI(id ="login"),
  
  #show the full view of the app after login
  uiOutput("fullview"),
) #fluid ui end


#SERVER FUNCTIONS
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
#Query Postgres and ingest needed tables into reactive environment
  
  
# alignment_aim <- dbReadTable(conn = con,"ta_plan_aim")
  
  #create a function to handle credentials
  credentials <- shinyauthr::loginServer(
    id = "login",
    data = user_base,
    user_col = user,
    pwd_col = password,
    sodium_hashed = TRUE,
    log_out = reactive(logout_init())
  )
  
  # Logout to hide
  logout_init <- shinyauthr::logoutServer(
    id = "logout",
    active = reactive(credentials()$user_auth)
  )
  

  #render ui
  output$fullview <- renderUI({
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    navbarPage(
      title=("PaTTAN Training Plan Management System"),
      tabPanel("Home", #matrix1
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                 ),
                 mainPanel(
                 )
               )
      ),
      tabPanel("Create and Modify Training Plans",
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   width = 2,
                   h4(strong("Directions")),
                   p("[Insert directions about how to create, modify 
                     and view the training plans]"
                     ,style = "font-size:13px"),
                   selectizeInput("initiative_selector",
                                  h5(strong("Component Plan")),
                                  choices = list(
                                    "Accessible Instructional Materials (AIM) Center",
                                    "Alternate Education for Disruptive Youth",
                                    "Assistive Technology",
                                    "Autism",
                                    "Blind - Visual Impairment",
                                    "Corrections",
                                    "Deaf-Blind",
                                    "Deaf and Hard of Hearing",
                                    "Family Engagement",
                                    "Inclusive Practices",
                                    "Intensive Interagency",
                                    "Learning Environment and Engagement",
                                    "Literacy",
                                    "Math",
                                    "MTSS/RtI Academics",
                                    "MTSS English Learners",
                                    "MTSS Equity",
                                    "Paraprofessionals",
                                    "Publications",
                                    "School Psychologist",
                                    "Secondary Transition",
                                    "Significant Cognitive Disabilities",
                                    "Special Education Law",
                                    "Special Education Leadership",
                                    "Speech & Language",
                                    "State Personnel Development Grant",
                                    "State Systemic Improvement Plan",
                                    "Increasing Graduation Rates/ Decreasing Dropout Rates",
                                    "STEM/Computer Science",
                                    "Supporting Students with Disabilities in Virtual Environments"
                                  )
                   ),
                   p("You can type the name of the intitiative to filter and 
                     select it from the drop down menu above. Use backspace 
                     within the white box to delete your typed text.",
                     style = "font-size:13px;"),
                   selectizeInput("Office_Selector",
                                  h5(strong("Select Lead Office for Intitative")),
                                  choices = list(
                                    "test",
                                    "test2")
                   ),
                   selectizeInput("State_lead_select",
                                  h5(strong("Select State Leads for Intitative")),
                                  multiple = TRUE,
                                  choices = list(
                                    "test",
                                    "test2"
                                  )
                   ),
                   p("Click the blank box above to select a lead or co-leads. 
                     A menu will appear. Use the backspace key to delete one 
                     or more of your choices",
                     style = "font-size:13px;"),
                   br(),
                   actionButton("save","Save Edits"),
                   br(),
                   br(),
                   downloadLink("download_plan",h5("Download Plan"))
                 ),
                 mainPanel(
                   tabsetPanel(
                     tabPanel("Create / Update Projects",
                              h3(strong("Implementation Alignment")),
                              rHandsontableOutput('alignment'),
                     ),
                     tabPanel("Projects Overview"),
                   )#end of tabsetPanel
                 ) #main panel end
               ) #sidebar layout end
      ) #end tab panel for create / edit plans
    ) #Navbar end
  })

  # save user edited values back to alignment tables
  
  observeEvent(input$save,{
      alignment_aim <<- hot_to_r(input$alignment)
  })

  #configure ui server functions
  output$alignment <- renderRHandsontable({
      rhandsontable(
        if (input$initiative_selector =="Accessible Instructional Materials (AIM) Center"){
          alignment_aim
        } else if
          (input$initiative_selector =="Alternate Education for Disruptive Youth") {
          alignment_alt_ed_dis_yth
          } else if (input$initiative_selector =="Assistive Technology") {
          alignment_assitive_tech
          } else if (input$initiative_selector =="Autism") {
            alignment_autism
          } else if (input$initiative_selector =="Blind - Visual Impairment") {
            alignment_blind_vi
          }
        ,rowHeaders = FALSE) %>%
        hot_table(stretchH = "all") %>%
        hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) %>%
      hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit=FALSE)
  })
  
output$download_plan <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste("PDE_Training_Plan-",input$initiative_selector,"-",Sys.Date(),".csv",sep="")
  },
  content = function(file){
    write.csv(hot_to_r(input$alignment),file,row.names = TRUE)
  }
)


#debugging alignment matrix
  # observeEvent(input$alignment, {
  #   # test_df = hot_to_r(input$alignment)
  #   print(alignment_aim)
  # })
# 
#   observeEvent(input$alignment, {
#     test_df = hot_to_r(input$alignment)
#     column6 <- test_df[,6]
#     print(column6)
#   })

  
} #end of server function

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Use the following to make example, empty data frames so that the app can run. I've only included a few from the selectinput.

```
alignment_aim <- data.table(
  Components = c("LRE (A)","High Incidence (B)",
                      "Low Incidence (C)","Equitable Practices (D)",
                      "Pillar Measues","Pillar Outcomes"),
  attract_prep_retain = rep(c(""),6),
  fam_engagement = rep(c(""),6),
  sec_trans = rep(c(""),6),
  instruct_dev = rep(c(""),6),
  Learning_Env_Eng = rep(c(""),6),
  component_measures = rep(c(""),6)
)

alignment_alt_ed_dis_yth <- data.table(
  Components = c("LRE (A)","High Incidence (B)",
                 "Low Incidence (C)","Equitable Practices (D)",
                 "Pillar Measues","Pillar Outcomes"),
  attract_prep_retain = rep(c(""),6),
  fam_engagement = rep(c(""),6),
  sec_trans = rep(c(""),6),
  instruct_dev = rep(c(""),6),
  Learning_Env_Eng = rep(c(""),6),
  component_measures = rep(c(""),6)
)

alignment_assitive_tech <- data.table(
  Components = c("LRE (A)","High Incidence (B)",
                 "Low Incidence (C)","Equitable Practices (D)",
                 "Pillar Measues","Pillar Outcomes"),
  attract_prep_retain = rep(c(""),6),
  fam_engagement = rep(c(""),6),
  sec_trans = rep(c(""),6),
  instruct_dev = rep(c(""),6),
  Learning_Env_Eng = rep(c(""),6),
  component_measures = rep(c(""),6)
)

alignment_autism <- data.table(
  Components = c("LRE (A)","High Incidence (B)",
                 "Low Incidence (C)","Equitable Practices (D)",
                 "Pillar Measues","Pillar Outcomes"),
  attract_prep_retain = rep(c(""),6),
  fam_engagement = rep(c(""),6),
  sec_trans = rep(c(""),6),
  instruct_dev = rep(c(""),6),
  Learning_Env_Eng = rep(c(""),6),
  component_measures = rep(c(""),6)
)

alignment_blind_vi <- data.table(
  Components = c("LRE (A)","High Incidence (B)",
                 "Low Incidence (C)","Equitable Practices (D)",
                 "Pillar Measues","Pillar Outcomes"),
  attract_prep_retain = rep(c(""),6),
  fam_engagement = rep(c(""),6),
  sec_trans = rep(c(""),6),
  instruct_dev = rep(c(""),6),
  Learning_Env_Eng = rep(c(""),6),
  component_measures = rep(c(""),6)
)
```

**UPDATE:**

Isolating input$intitiative_selector is the fix

```
  observeEvent(input$save,{
    if (isolate(input$initiative_selector) =="Accessible Instructional Materials (AIM) Center"){
      alignment_aim <<- hot_to_r(input$alignment) 
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who experiences this issue. Isolating the select input within an if statement will solve it by not taking a dependency on the input. I used reactlog to see what was occurring.

```
 # save user edited values back to alignment tables
  observeEvent(input$save,{
    if (isolate(input$initiative_selector) =="Accessible Instructional Materials (AIM) Center"){
      alignment_aim <<- hot_to_r(input$alignment) 
      } else if (isolate(input$initiative_selector) =="Alternate Education for Disruptive Youth") {
          alignment_alt_ed_dis_yth <<- hot_to_r(input$alignment)
      } else if (isolate(input$initiative_selector) =="Assistive Technology") {
        alignment_assitive_tech <<- hot_to_r(input$alignment)
      } else if (isolate(input$initiative_selector) =="Autism") {
        alignment_autism <<- hot_to_r(input$alignment)
      } else if (isolate(input$initiative_selector) =="Blind - Visual Impairment") {
        alignment_blind_vi <<- hot_to_r(input$alignment)
      }
  })
  
  #configure ui server functions
  output$alignment <- renderRHandsontable({
      rhandsontable(
        if (input$initiative_selector =="Accessible Instructional Materials (AIM) Center"){
          alignment_aim
        } else if
          (input$initiative_selector =="Alternate Education for Disruptive Youth") {
          alignment_alt_ed_dis_yth
          } else if (input$initiative_selector =="Assistive Technology") {
          alignment_assitive_tech
          } else if (input$initiative_selector =="Autism") {
            alignment_autism
          } else if (input$initiative_selector =="Blind - Visual Impairment") {
            alignment_blind_vi
          }
        ,rowHeaders = FALSE) %>%
        hot_table(stretchH = "all") %>%
        hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) %>%
      hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit=FALSE)
  })
```